# Where can I find a list of buff and debuff IDs?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm setting up the [Need To Know](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/need-to-know.aspx) addon and want to track the duration of the Hemorrhage debuff on my current target. Since the ability applies multiple debuffs with the name "Hemorrhage", I need to specify the specific debuff I want to track by ID instead of name.

I can't seem to find a list of buff/debuff IDs anywhere on the web, though. Help me Gaming, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are just Spell IDs and the easiest way I know to find them is to find the right spell/action on [Wowhead](http://wowhead.com) and grab the number out of the URL.

For Hemorrhage, there are a few results:

- http://www.wowhead.com/spell=16511 - This is Hemorrhage.
- http://www.wowhead.com/spell=89775 - This is the second debuff that gets applied when using Glyph of Hemorrhage.

The complete search results are [here](http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=hemorrhage).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that spell IDs and buff IDs were the same thing.